# Shell script w/ zsh for tmux

Tags: shell, console, zsh, tmux

I've been watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5r6yzFEXajQ) on youtube, and at 41:00, he uses a command he wrote himself (available [here](https://github.com/nicknisi/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/tm)). The script allows us to manage all the tmux sessions just by typing `tm`. Example :

```
Available sessions
------------------

1) test
2) New Session
3) zsh
Please choose your session:
```

I've tried to "install" it on my computer but can't get the script to work properly. It works fine when I want to use the programm. But when I'm logged into a session and want to quit this session, I write the usual command (`tmux kill-session`), and then a big "confusion" appears : because I have written `tmux` (or `tm`), the computer thinks I am calling the programm. And at line 4 there's a condition that makes the script abort if I'm already in a tmux session. So whenevere I am in a session and want to use a tmux command, it aborts. Here is the line in my .zshrc :

```
alias tmux=".dotfiles/tmux/tmux_menu.zsh"
```

How do I solve this problem ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see the merit of using this script. You can get the list of sessions with `tmux ls`, you can create a new session with `tmux new -s MySessionName`. To attach to an existing session: `tmux att -t MyExistingSessionName`. To open a login shell, call `zsh -l`. And if you want to close a tmux session from within that session, either close all windows or do `<C-b>kill-session`.

Comment: @kba I know that, I just  find it more comfortable to use this script. And i can't get  it to work properelly ^^

Comment: If your alias overrides `tmux`, you can force zsh to look for the binary `tmux` by prepending `command`. E.g. `command tmux kill-session` will execute `/usr/bin/tmux kill-session`. Still, I'd recommend you set your alias to something else (like `tmux-menu`), so you get used to the syntax of the real tool, especially if you're using tmux on different machines.

Comment: @kba But that would mean I would have to do an alias for every tmux command in  m'y .zshrc. How could  I add a condition that says : "if i am in  a zsh session or if there are some  parameters  with the command, then override the  script"

Comment: Can't follow you I'm afraid. If you make an alias `alias tmux=xyz` and enter `tmux` in an interactive shell, the alias will take precedence over entries in your `$PATH`. If you **want** to ignore the alias for a single command, you can either specify the full path to the binary (`/usr/bin/tmux kill-session`) or, as above, `command tmux kill-session`.

Comment: @kba Actually, I think I have a solution. I could modify my .zshrc by adding a ‘if‘ instruction : if there is no parameter with the command, then use the script i downloaded. Otherwise, use the tmux binary. --- if this seems right, i will try it tomorrow (because i'm french and it's 1.30am where i live)

Comment: Hello again, so I've been trying to do what i've said i would do. Again, this is in my .zshrc : `alias tmux="~.dotfiles/tmux/tmux.zsh"`. This is tmux.zsh :
`#!/bin/sh  
if [ -z $0 ]  
then  
     source ~/.dotfiles/tmux/tmux_menu.zsh  
fi`
The other file (the one displaying the menu) didn't change. Now, when I try to run the command `tmux` or `tm`, nothing happens. I don't know what to do...

P.S.: Sorry, i don't know how to display code on multiple lines

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

> I could modify my .zshrc by adding a ‘if‘ instruction : if there is no
>   parameter with the command, then use the script i downloaded.
>   Otherwise, use the tmux binary.
>
> … this is in my .zshrc : `alias tmux="~.dotfiles/tmux/tmux.zsh"`.
>   This is tmux.zsh :
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> if [ -z $0 ]
> then source ~/.dotfiles/tmux/tmux_menu.zsh
> fi
> ```
>
> The other file (the one displaying the menu) didn't change. Now, when
>   I try to run the command `tmux` or `tm`, nothing happens. I don't know
>   what to do...

`$0` isn't a command parameter - although nowhere in `man zshall` stated, just as with other shells `$0` is set to the name of the script (`~/.dotfiles/tmux/tmux.zsh`); `$1` is set to the first argument.